# Impala running query with variables

Tags: hive, impala, hue

Does anyone know how to get this to work in Hue Impala?

```
drop table if exists user_db.$(user_initial)_ $(issue)_ $(extract_date) purge;
```

The issue is when I remove the spaces the variables disappear on Hue. Might not be possible but wanted to check